# How can I get a selected position in Android Studio Maps Activity and get back to main activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I am working with Android Studio and I want to open a Google Maps map on a current location. After that, the user could select a new location, and what I want is to get back that new location to the main activity where the map was launched.

I initialize the GoogleMaps Activity from the main activity with an intent and pass a current location name, for later, in the maps activity, decode to latitude and longitude, like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String localizacion = intent.getStringExtra("localizacion");
        double latitude = 43.363648;
        double longitude = -2.501341;

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(localizacion, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(addresses != null){
            if(addresses.size() > 0) {
                latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
            }
        }

        ...TODO...
```

How can I open the map in a current position, and, when the user select a new position, how can I get back to the previous activity?